# Send jquery array via ajax into rails controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i need to send one array into rails controller via jquery ajax

jquery CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 2;
$("#addButton").click(function () {
   var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

   newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="text" placeholder="Role" name="Role' + 
   counter + 
      '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" > <input type="text" 
placeholder="Search" name="search' + counter + 
      '" id="se" value="" >');

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
counter++;
});



$("#getButton").click(function () {
var fd = new FormData($("#movie-form")[0]); 
var name = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
var arr = [];
var msg = '';
for(i=1; i<counter;i++){
  msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val(); 
      arr[i] = $('#textbox' + i).val();
}
 $.each(arr,function(index, item)
{   
     alert(index);
     alert(item);
   }
);

fd.append( 'file', name);
fd.append( 'file22', name);
$.ajax({
url: '/create',
data: {fd:fd,arr:arr},
processData: false,
contentType: false,
type: 'POST',
success: function(data){
alert(data);
}
});
return false;
});
```

But it shows the error

**Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:
REXML::ParseException (The document "[object Object]" does not have a valid root):**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you console.log your array? That'll be much easer and you can inspect the sub elements when you click on it. In FireFox (with FireBug plugin installed) or in Chrome press F12 to open the dev tools and see the console.

I don't think this will work for IE but you can convert a JavaScript object to JSON with JSON.stringify so you can send your msg as JSON:

try:

```
for(i=1; i<counter;i++){
      arr[i] = $('#textbox' + i).val();
}
msg= JSON.stringify(arr)
```

The error you're having is from your rails app but you have not posted any code where that error happens.

I'm not sure what rexml does in rails so can't realy help you with that one.

Answer (score 3):

To do an ajax POST request via jquery the data has to be a string.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/create",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    function(data){
        alert(data)
    }
});
```

Watch out for JSON being undefined in IE6/7.  If you need to target those browsers, use this:  https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js