# Fetch items via ajax request on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I have the select tag and embedded options tag. I got help here, [Jquery Filter next select group based on selection of previous select group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324802/jquery-filter-next-select-group-based-on-selection-of-previous-select-group), 
on how to filter the next select group based on selection of previous select group.

There are a LOT of options in the deeper layers, so I want to know how I can do this with an ajax request. I would like the layer2 (and deeper layers) to be populated through ajax.

Below is some toy html, again from here, [Jquery Filter next select group based on selection of previous select group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324802/jquery-filter-next-select-group-based-on-selection-of-previous-select-group),
demonstrating how to affect a deeper multiselect box with a previous layer using jquery that I got help from.

```
<select id="layer1" multiple="multiple">
  <option data-id="3">Chocolate</option>
  <option data-id="5">Cookie</option>
</select>

<select id="layer2" data-depends-on="layer1" multiple="multiple">
  <option data-parent="3" data-id="6">Milk Chocolate</option>
  <option data-parent="5" data-id="7">Sprinkled Cookie</option>
  <option data-parent="5" data-id="8">Iced Cookie</option>
</select>

<script>
$("select").each(function(){
    // cache all options
    $(this).data('options', $('option', this));
}).on('change', function(e){
    var current = this, selected = [];

    // find all selected for the current select and
    // store them in a local variable
    $('option:selected', current).each(function(){
        selected.push($(this).data('id'));
    });

    // find all selects that depend on this one.
    $("select").filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('depends-on') === current.id;
    }).each(function(){
        // search our cached options and filter them
        // by the selected option(s).  Store them in
        // a local variable.
        var children = $(this).data('options').filter(function(){
            return selected.indexOf($(this).data('parent')) > -1;
        });

        // empty and repopulate the select with the
        // filtered results. Also, trigger the next
        // select so the effect cascades.
        $(this).empty().append(children).trigger('change');
    });
}).trigger('change'); // trigger change so it filters
                      // on page load.
                      </script>
```

Here is some rails code and corresponding view to give a sense of how I'm doing it with rails.
Rails code

```
  def new
    @one = CategoryLevelOne.all.map { |c| [c.id, c.name] }
    @two = CategoryLevelTwo.all.map { |c| [c.id, c.name] }
  end
```

corresponding view

```
<%=form_tag('/companies', method: :post)%>
    <select name="category_id[]" id="layer1" multiple="multiple" size="20">
      <%= render 'companies/list/category_one' %>
    </select>
    <select name="category_id2[]" data-depends-on="layer1" id="layer2" multiple="multiple" size="20">
      <%= render 'companies/list/category_two' %>
    </select>
<%= submit_tag%>
 //the same jquery script is used as in the above code
```

companies/list/_category_one.html.erb

```
<% @one.each do |c| %>
  <option data-id=<%=c[0]%>  value=<%=c[1]%>><%=c[1]%></option>
<% end %>
```

I would like to do an ajax request, that does a GET request to a controller action, fetch an object, and using the object, create/update a bunch of option tags inside a specified select tag.

So I imagine it would look something like this

ajax request triggers a certain GET request for a certain controller action
In that controller action, it gets a certain array of objects, and returns it in the form of json. 
The javascript that takes that array and is able to do something similar to

```
<% @one.each do |c| %>
<option data-id=<%=c[0]%> style="color:<%=c[2]%>" value=<%=c[1]%>><%=c[1]%></option>
<% end %>
```

for a specific select tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we make make ajax call to server on select tag change with respective id data id.

Then from params[:id] and fetch respective data from it, and attach this data dynamically to another select tag from ajax success. (recreate option tag dynamically.)

Ex. 2 Select tags - country & state

Depending on country selection, state should change.

Please refer below code for it.

In View:

```
<%= f.select :country, @countries, id: "country" %>

<%= f.select :state, @states, id: "state" %>
```

In JS:

```
$("#country").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "get_states/"+$(this).val(),
      corssDomain: true,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
         var listItems = "<option value=''>Select</option>";
         $.each(data,function(key,value){
         listItems+= "<option value='" + value.id + "'>" + value.state_name + "</option>";
         });
         $("#state").html(listItems);
         //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      },

      error : function(data) {

      }
   });
 });
```

In Controller -

```
def get_states
  country = Country.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if country  
    @states = country.states
    render :json => @states
  end
end
```

In Routes -

```
get 'get_states/:id' => 'users#get_states'
```

Hopefully this example will help.

Comment: wow nice. do you know how I can do this with an array of id's.send an array of id's to the controller. I basically want to fetch a bunch of entries that match any of an array of id's.

Comment: @user3916997 Please refer this que. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435895/send-jquery-array-via-ajax-into-rails-controller or better you can make a string of id's by Comma separated and pass though ajax request, then split that string by comma in controller and do further processing.